# recursive tsql sql optimization yet again

Tags: sql-server, recursive-query

I'm trying to make a table with a hierarchical structure where the parent is equal to the sum of the children as is typical.
My baseline task table below is the typical

taskid, taskparentid, value, baseline

table that I make with a cte.  Hopefully afterwards, the code is clear, if terrible:

```
    with 
basetable (taskbaselinework, taskid, projectid, parenttaskid, baselinenumber, taskoutlinenumber) as (
    select taskbaselinework, t.taskid, t.projectid, iif(t.parenttaskid =t.taskid,null,parenttaskid) parenttaskid, baselinenumber, taskoutlinenumber from m.tasks t
        left join m.TaskBaselines b on t.taskid = b.taskid
        where parenttaskid is not null
        --and t.projectid in ('6DD43DF1-D1FB-E511-80D6-00155D001E10')

)
, cte (taskid, parenttaskid, taskbaselinework, baselinenumber) as
(
  select t.taskId, t.ParenttaskId, t.taskbaselinework, t.baselinenumber
  from basetable t
  where t.ParenttaskId is null
  union all
  select t.taskId, t.parenttaskid, t.taskbaselinework, t.baselinenumber
  from cte c
  join basetable t on t.ParenttaskId = c.taskId and (c.baselinenumber = t.baselinenumber or c.baselinenumber is null)

)
select c1.taskId, c1.ParenttaskId, coalesce(c1.baselinenumber,c2.baselinenumber) baselinenumber, coalesce(c1.taskbaselinework, sum(isnull(c2.taskbaselinework,0))) taskbaselinework
into m.bt2
from cte c1
left outer join cte c2 on c1.taskid = c2.parenttaskid and (c1.baselinenumber = c2.baselinenumber or c1.baselinenumber is null)
group by c1.taskId, c1.ParenttaskId,  coalesce(c1.baselinenumber,c2.baselinenumber), c1.taskbaselinework
having not coalesce(c1.baselinenumber,c2.baselinenumber) is null and coalesce(c1.taskbaselinework, sum(isnull(c2.taskbaselinework,0))) > 0
order by taskid
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 20);
```

I wish I was better at formatting code on this platform.

Anyway, this takes 6 hours.  The biggest chunk is the fact that it's doing a clustered index scan on m.baselines.taskid 26k times reading 947MM lines and m.task 30k times reading 16bn lines because of the recursion.  If I take out basetable as a cte and make it a normal table, it gets read once and the query runs in 12 seconds.  So, how do I fix this and still keep the baselines cte

Comment: `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 20)` is invalid for Postgres. That looks more like SQL Server's T-SQL, but not Postgres

Comment: And I dont know what `IIF(...)` means.

Comment: Oh my god!  Right.  This is t-sql. I'm so used to posting about postgre I forgot I'm doing tsql.  I have to change the flag!!

Answer (score 0):

The trick to avoid CTEs is to replace them by TEMP VIEWS. This will preserve the table structure and indexes can be used.

---

```
CREATE TEMP VIEW basetable (taskbaselinework, taskid, projectid, parenttaskid, baselinenumber, taskoutlinenumber) AS
SELECT taskbaselinework -- <<== QUALIFY THIS!!
        , t.taskid, t.projectid
        , COALESCE(t.parenttaskid ,t.taskid) parenttaskid -- <<== NOT SURE
        , baselinenumber, taskoutlinenumber
        FROM m.tasks t
        LEFT JOIN m.TaskBaselines b on t.taskid = b.taskid
        WHERE parenttaskid IS NOT NULL -- <<== QUALIFY THIS!
        ;

WITH cte (taskid, parenttaskid, taskbaselinework, baselinenumber) AS
(
  SELECT t.taskId, t.ParenttaskId, t.taskbaselinework, t.baselinenumber
  FROM basetable t
  WHERE t.ParenttaskId IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.taskId, t.parenttaskid, t.taskbaselinework, t.baselinenumber
  FROM cte c
  JOIN basetable t ON t.ParenttaskId = c.taskId
                 AND c.baselinenumber = t.baselinenumber OR c.baselinenumber IS NULL
)
SELECT c1.taskId, c1.ParenttaskId
        , COALESCE(c1.baselinenumber,c2.baselinenumber) baselinenumber
        , COALESCE(c1.taskbaselinework
        , SUM(ISNULL(c2.taskbaselinework,0))) taskbaselinework
INTO m.bt2
FROM cte c1
LEFT outer join cte c2 ON c1.taskid = c2.parenttaskid AND (c1.baselinenumber = c2.baselinenumber OR c1.baselinenumber IS NULL)
GROUP BY c1.taskId, c1.ParenttaskId
        ,  COALESCE(c1.baselinenumber,c2.baselinenumber)
        , c1.taskbaselinework
HAVING NOT COALESCE(c1.baselinenumber,c2.baselinenumber) IS NULL
   AND COALESCE(c1.taskbaselinework, sum(isnull(c2.taskbaselinework,0))) > 0
ORDER BY taskid
        ;
```

---

There seems to be a lot of code duplication and superfluous NULL checks in the SQL, but I am too lazy to understand their intention.

Comment: How could I know?